Can Postfix be used to deliver e-mail internally only?
I've set up a Rocky server and would like to deliver notifications from apps internally using Postfix (rather than needing to look at logs). An example would be smartd delivering an e-mail when there is an HDD issue. Rocky already has the Postfix mail server installed.
Internally, I will pick up the e-mail using another machine with an e-mail client (on which I will configure connectivity to the internal server).
Is that possible? All the guides I read cover the more typical scenario of connecting the internet and acting as an e-mail relay.
I can configure it using either the command line editing of files or the Webmin interface.

By default most Linux SMTP servers, including postfix, will deliver e-mail to local users without any additional configuration. If your login is "pete" simply sending a message with the local mail facility (mail , mailx ,  /usr/lib/sendmail etc etc  )  to pete without appending a domain should get delivered to a mailbox, typically /var/spool/mail/pete - You'll need to install an POP3 or IMAP server to be able to remotely check that mailbox.
